# Cannot remove value storage ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to remove value in Ionic3 storage but i can't:
item is the id of the station

```
removeItem(item){

     this.storage.get('thestations').then((val) => {

            for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) 
            {

              if(val[i].id == item) {
                 this.storage.remove(i);
              }
            } 
        });
    }
```

I also tried that to delete the row with the key number 5 but still the same problem:
 `this.storage.remove('5');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, the storage is a key value store. so when you want to delete an entire item you need to call storage.remove(key)
however when you have an array stored and want to remove an item you need to get the array first, modify it and then save it again.

you cannot work/delete on the storage reference